# Android RecyclerView column amount based on item width in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout

I'd like to get similar effect with `GridLayoutManager/adapter` with `RecyclerView`
like shown at the picture - columns amount does not depend on screen width, but on the item with (text width).

So far I've found only solutions how to depend columns amount based on screen width.

[example picture to show the desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqKGX.png)

Comment: [flexboxlayoutmanager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

Answer (score 2):

You should use FlexBoxLayout instead.

For this, first you have to add the following dependency in your build.gradle file.

```
    dependencies {

              implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'    
             }
```

To use flex layout with recyclerview. You should add following lines of code in your
MainActivity:

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) 
    context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
    layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
    layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
    layoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.CENTER);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Then you can attach your adapter to recyclerView and you are done!

Comment: thank you so much, it was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: much love brother. This was super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- GridView: A ViewGroup that shows the items in a two-dimensional scrolling grid. In Grid View, each grid is of the same size .i.e., the height and width of each grid are equal. It shows symmetric items in the views.
- Staggered GridView: This ViewGroup is the extension of Grid View. In this view, the Grid is of varying size .i.e., their height and width may vary. It shows asymmetric items in the views. It automatically sets the item views according to its height and width.

For your given picture **StaggeredGridLayoutManager()** will be the perfect choice with a recycler view. Check out the article below.
[RecyclerView as Staggered Grid in Android With Example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-in-android-with-example/)